# How to compute the probability of sampling $f(t+\Delta t) > f(t)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

### The Setup

Suppose I have a periodic function $f(t+T) = f(t)$, say this describes the motion of a particle confined in a box. Now suppose I do the following experiment:

1. Choose some initial position (or some initial time, since $f$ is periodic), $x_0 = f(t_0)$, where $t_0 \in [0,T]$
2. From this $t_0$, observe the position of the particle $f(t)$ at finite time steps of size $\Delta t < T$ (i.e. sample the values $f(t_0), f(t_0 + \Delta t), f(t_0 + 2\Delta t), ...$)
3. For every sampled value (except for the initial one), compute $\Delta f = f(t_0 + n\Delta t) - f(t_0 + (n-1)\Delta t)$. Denote the event $(+)$ if $\Delta f > 0$ (the particle had gone further) and the event $(-)$ if $\Delta f < 0$ (the particle had moved back).
4. Repeat the measurement $N$ times, letting $N \rightarrow \infty$

My question is, given $f(t)$ is an analytic function, or at least something that has a Fourier Series, is there a way to compute analytically the probability of observing the events $(+)$ and $(-)$ in any one trial over the $N$ measurements?

(Of course I can get whether it is $(+)$ or $(-)$ exactly at anytime using the $f$, but what I want is the statistics of this thought experiment)

---

### My Naive Attempt

For definiteness, choose $f(t) = \sin{\omega t}$ with $\Delta t = 1$. Since $f(t)$ is periodic with period $T = \frac{2\pi}{\omega} > \Delta t$, $\Delta f$ is also periodic with $T$, and it should (I think) suffice to consider just one period. Moreover, as $N \rightarrow \infty$, I would expect the importance of the initial condition $t_0$ become less and less (the validity of this I personally find questionable), hence I form the probability by explicitly constructing

$$P(+) = \frac{1}{T}\int_{\Delta f >0} dt$$

which is $\frac{1}{2}$ since $\Delta f$ is symmetric. But this doesn't even convince myself.

---

### Summarizing the Question

To summarize, I would like to ask:

1. What would be the right way to mathematically formulate the calculation of $P(+)$ and $P(-)$, given any initial $t_0$ (maybe with an initial distribution $\rho(f(t_0))$? )
2. If the probabilities can be computed, can they be generalized to the one-step probabilities $P(+|+), P(-|+)$, etc?

P.S. My background is from physics, so I am not too concern about rigor. Probability is just one thing that I use all time but never received a formal in-depth training on, so I just need some guidance on how to start on this problem.

Comment: There is no probabilistic material in problem so how do you define a probability in this case?

Comment: @Mostafa Ayaz Probability in terms of relative frequency and statistics. For example, the classical harmonic oscillator is a completely deterministic system. But we can still define a probability density for it (see http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ProbabilityDensityForAClassicalHarmonicOscillator/ ) in the sense of "What is the probability I will see the mass at position $x$ if I look at it right now". There is a similar probabilistic formalism in treating other deterministic dynamical systems (iterative maps and differential equations).

Comment: And what I wanted to do in here is similar to that: Even though everything is deterministic, I don't want to carry all the details along. Over the total $N$ measurements, sometime I will observe (+) and sometime (-), and hopefully as $N \rightarrow \infty$, the relative frequency of occuring (+) / (-) will converge to some value. This value will tell me how likely I will observe (+) / (-) in any given trial, regardless of the exact time $t$ I perform the measurement.